# Leave specific file on server when running bitbucket pipeline using rsync

Tags: rsync, git, deployment

I have a bitbucket pipeline setup to rsync to a server that hosts a Wordpress Site. The files on the server initially have a skeleton Wordpress site with a wp-config.php & wp-config-sample.php but all the other wp files will be sent over.

When I run my pipeline how do I make sure that the wp-config & wp-config-sample remain on the server after the pipeline has run (I have wp-config.php in a gitignore so it's never sent over)

Pipeline code is here:

```
# pipelines deployment configuration
# -----
# Staging deployment happens with every push of the development branch.
#
# To run the Production deployment, access the repository > latest commit page,
# click on "Run Pipeline" and select "Custom: Production" from the dropdown.
# -----
# DO NOT change any of the variables below. To set them go to: PROJECT > Settings > Pipelines > Repository Variables
# Make sure the development branch is correctly named below - "develop" is being used below

image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  branches:
    develop: #name of the development branch
      - step:
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/rsync-deploy:0.3.1
              variables:
                USER: $STAGING_USER
                SERVER: ''
                REMOTE_PATH: $STAGING_PATH
                LOCAL_PATH: './'
                EXTRA_ARGS: '-p --exclude-from=exclude-pipelines.txt'
            - ssh $STAGING_USER@ "find $STAGING_FOLDER. -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755"
            - ssh $STAGING_USER@ "find $STAGING_FOLDER. -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644"
    main: #name of the development branch
      - step:
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/rsync-deploy:0.3.1
              variables:
                USER: $PRODUCTION_USER
                SERVER: ''
                REMOTE_PATH: $PRODUCTION_PATH
                LOCAL_PATH: './'
                EXTRA_ARGS: '-p --exclude-from=exclude-pipelines.txt'
            - ssh $PRODUCTION_USER@ "find public_html/. -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755"
            - ssh $PRODUCTION_USER@ "find public_html/. -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644"
  custom:
    Production:
      - step:
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/rsync-deploy:0.3.1
              variables:
                USER: $PRODUCTION_USER
                SERVER: ''
                REMOTE_PATH: $PRODUCTION_PATH
                LOCAL_PATH: './'
                EXTRA_ARGS: '-p --exclude-from=exclude-pipelines.txt'
            - ssh $PRODUCTION_USER@ "find public_html/. -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755"
            - ssh $PRODUCTION_USER@ "find public_html/. -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644"
```